# let Win or Mac user start a script on my unix box

Tags: networking, remote

I have a python script with a single parameter (tablename) on a UNIX box that I want to expose it to my colleagues on the corporate intranet.
I.e. I want to let certain users from different systems run the program on a specific machine. Is there a standard solution for this?

The script has no output that's required to be shown back to user. The colleagues have all possible OSes and I'd like to have a simple minimalistic solution, that anyone could use and is easy for me to install. Something like typing 'telnet hostname scriptname tablename' into a shell/cmd prompt on their system would do for an interface. No authentication is needed. I can create a web interface, of course, but it seems to be overkill for a task as simple as this.

If it can be done with telnet, could you point me to an example?

Comment: So you want to let certain users from different systems run the program on a specific machine and collect its output?

Comment: Yes, I want them to kick off the program as you describe. But there is no output for them to collect (they will see the results as an update of the specified database table ). If they can see the stdout and stderr of the script that won't hurt, but it is not necessary.

Comment: I would recommend providing a web server interface. There is a standalone [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) server library - no need for apache and all that.  Whatever it costs you to implement you will gain in not having to explain to your users how to telnet or whatever.

Comment: @Diego Please edit your post to clarify what you want.

Comment: @countermode I am not sure what to clarify. "The script has no output that's required to be shown back to user" is saying it loud and clear, isn't it? I am not a native speaker, so this may be just the language thing, happy to correct that.

Comment: Clarify your original post, not the answer to the comment.

Comment: @meuh, pls. consider adding your comment as an answer, if you care.

Comment: @countermode Ah, OK, this is the part "want to let certain users from different systems run the program on a specific machine", I guess. I have added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a tiny standalone [python3 server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) (similar for python2) that just shows an html button that you can push to generate a POST request that you can use to run your program. The actual urls are ignored in this simple code. You should check for reasonable values etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315334/119298
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer 

body = """
 <body><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/runcmd">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Do Update">
       </form>
 <hr>
"""
class handlerequest(BaseHTTPRequestHandler): 
    def do_POST(self):
        # run my command. if ok:
        reply = "result was ok"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(body+reply, "utf8"))

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(body, "utf8"))

server = HTTPServer(('', 80), handlerequest) 
server.serve_forever()
```

If you already have a server listening on port 80 you will need to change the above of course.   The use of a POST instead of just a GET url makes the browser ask the user to confirm the post if they just do a refresh. This is standard for cgi's that have "side-effects".

Comment: This looks like just what the doctor ordered! Thanks!  I have already set up a page using your suggestion so I will add your "post" code and will come back to confirm.

Comment: Do you know what modification should be done to the "runcmd" in order to be able to launch it this way? I have got your script doing what it supposed to do judging by the HTML output. But the runcmd does not start. I have the #!/usr/bin/python3 included there, chmoded to u+x and it runs as ./runcmd from my user shell session.

Comment: ah, OK, pls disregard the previous comment, the actual command code goes where "# run my command. if ok:" is. I have added that to your answer, please confirm if that's fine for you. Thanks, that was it!

Comment: Yes, you can simply call `ok = os.system('my_script.py')` to run your real command, and test the return code with `if ok==0` to send back an ok or fail message. Or since your code is in python you could just import the file and then call some function in it at this point. You may need to modify it slightly, but that is for discussion in another question. Much python code is written to be run as a program, or imported as a library and run from some other program. It is one of its best features.